# Files written in a JSP page are not found by Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I've developed a JSP that writes a PNG file in a folder of deployment directory. After writing the contents, flushing, closing and syncing the file I try to show it in the same JSP using a  tag but most of the times the imatge doesn't appears in the renderized page on the browser (the request of  return a 404 Not Found response). The file is created (I can see the file into the folder in the system explorer).

I'm using Tomcat 8 as web container and I'm executing the webapp and Tomcat in the Eclipse Luna IDE.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The file system may impose locks on the files you have used recently and until these locks are released you can't read that file or it's reused by another process at the same time...

Comment: keep in mind that if the file is written to inside `WEB-INF` directory you will not be able to ask for it directly from the browser (IIRC)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has been answered before in a slightly different form:

[Tomcat 7 returns "304 Not Modified" on modified/non existent resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397080/tomcat-7-returns-304-not-modified-on-modified-non-existent-resource/20437973#20437973)

However, since you are probably only generating your PNG files once (or maybe not very often), you have IMO a valid use case.

Since Tomcat does do caching, I think that you might want to consider using `cachingAllowed="false"` on your `<Context>`. Note that you will likely observe a slight performance drop since Tomcat will be going to the disk for every static request instead of consulting its cache.

You also have the option of writing your own servlet to serve the auto-generated PNG files directly from the disk. It can be complicated to write your own static-resource servlet with all the bells and whistles that Tomcat's `DefaultServlet` supports, but you can skip a lot of that and just always serve the whole file regardless of what the clients requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew nothing about the Tomcat option "cachingAllowed". I'll try it.